# pptp: not found

Tags: vpn, ppp

Добрый день! Задача следующая - есть хост с виндузой и две виртуалки - xubuntu(1) и lubuntu(2). Задача - поднять под (1) VPN и подключить к нему виндузу и (2). Сервер успешно настроил, виндовый vpn-клиент подключается, а вот клиент с (2) не хочет, постоянно выстреливает следующее:

```
pppd: The remote system is required to authenticate itself 
pppd: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.
```

Никак не могу с этим справится. Вот листинг chap-secrets:

linux 192.168.255.128 moluli86 *
Вот листинг /etc/ppp/peers/vpn:

```
pty "192.168.255.128 --nolaunchpppd"
name linux
file /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
```

Прошу помощи в решении проблемы.

P.S.
Логи

```
Couldn't get channel number: Input/output error
Script pptp 192.168.255.128 --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 1641), status = 0x7f
using channel 1
sh: 1: pptp: not found
Failed to set PPP kernel option flags: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
Script pptp 192.168.255.128 --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 1720), status = 0x7f
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
using channel 2
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
sh: 1: pptp: not found
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
Script pptp 192.168.255.128 --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 1847), status = 0x7f
using channel 3
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
sh: 1: pptp: not found
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
Script pptp 192.168.255.128 --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 1856), status = 0x7f
using channel 4
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
sh: 1: pptp: not found
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
Script pptp 192.168.255.128 --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 1894), status = 0x7f
```

Comment: подсказка: попробуйте явно указать путь к этой программе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67670/discussion-on-question-by-igor-starovoyt-pptp-not-found).